# How to run two ExecutorService invokeAll() in parallel?

Tags: java, concurrency, executorservice

TLDR: I want to submit two lists of callables at the same time, but different timeout

---

Is there a way or the best alternative to running two invokeAll() commands at the same time with different timeouts?

Ex of blocking:

```
ExecutorService executorService1 = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
ExecutorService executorService2 = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

List<Callable<String>> callableTasks1;
List<Callable<String>> callableTasks2;

List<Future<String>> completed;

completed = executorService1.invokeAll(callableTasks1, 5, TimeUnit.Seconds);
completed.addAll(executorService1.invokeAll(callableTasks2, 2, TimeUnit.Seconds));
```

```
for(Future<String> s: completed) {
    if(s.isCancelled()) {
        System.out.println("It's cancelled");
    } else {
       try {
         System.out.println("Got it: " + s.get());
       } 
       catch(...) {
        ...
       }
    }
}
```

Submitting each task in a for loop:
executorService1.submit(task) and calling task.get(5, TimeUnit.Seconds)
seems to be running in sequence.

Comment: besides waiting on the results from more than one thread, which is the only way I can think of to wait for different amounts of times at the same time, there's probably at least a better way using two compound futures from `CompletableFuture.allOf` where you wait on the results sequentially but after submitting all your callables to the executor service(s) (your sample only uses executor1 btw). Also consider if there is really a reason to give one set of tasks only 2 seconds to complete when you will wait for 3 more seconds anyways on another set of tasks.

Comment: (Using executor1 for both is a typo). I'm trying wait for results from two threads but there I still have to wait for both to finish (with awaitTermination()).

5 and 2 is made up, my original difference is 5 seconds(each counts)
I'll read about "CompletableFuture.allOf", and continue to look for options. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I ended up with was waiting for the results from two threads.
Also instead of creating two threads for each call I ended up using another executorService to reuse the threads

Shortened version(doesn't run, modify to run):

```
ExecutorService executorService1 = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
ExecutorService executorService2 = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

List<Callable<String>> callableTasks1 = new ArrayList(3 callables);
List<Callable<String>> callableTasks2 = new ArrayList(2 callables);

List<Callable<Object>> callableObjectFutures = executorService2.invokeAll(
() -> {executorService1.invokeAll(invokeAll(callableTasks1, 5, TimeUnit.Seconds);},
() -> {executorService1.invokeAll(invokeAll(callableTasks2, 2, TimeUnit.Seconds);}
);

List<Future<String>> completed = callableObjectFutures.get(0).get();
completed.addAll(callableObjectFutures.get(1).get());
```